# jquery refresh div every second AND load a page with a get option

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically i want to reload page every second and the page needs a get option so its loading the page like page.php?id=123

My code:

```
function autoRefresh_div(data){
  $("#refreshbtn").load($.get("btn.php"));
}
setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this to get data with id:

```
function autoRefresh_div(id){
  $("#refreshbtn").load($.get("btn.php?id="+id));
}

setInterval(function(){ 
   autoRefresh_div(123); 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setInterval(function() {
    window.location = 'page.php?id=123';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: how do i make it so it loads btn.php?id=123 like that with the id part

Comment: I just edited my answer. Try this and let me know if it worked ;)